# Deducing means of normal distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a set of objects ($i$) with different lengths ($x_i$), and two devices ($a$ and $b$) to measure them. Each device measures with an error which probability density function (pdf) follows a normal distribution:

$x_i = x_{a_i} + \epsilon_a , \quad \epsilon_a \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_a,\sigma_{a}^{2})$

$x_i = x_{b_i} + \epsilon_b , \quad \epsilon_b \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_b,\sigma_{b}^{2})$

I know $\sigma_{a}$ and $\sigma_{b}$. Hence, if I knew $\mu_a$ and $\mu_b$ I could calculate the pdf of $x_i$. But don't know them. Can I deduce $\mu_a$ and $\mu_b$ from the measurements? Can I deduce them if I know their pdf? Can I deduce how are they related at least?

Comment: "..calculate the PDF of $x_i$" Are the $x_i$ random variables? If not then they don't have a PDF, and it seems to me that they are fixed here. The same remark if it comes to $\mu_a$ and $\mu_b$.

Comment: $x_i$ are fixed but unknown, $\mu_a$ and $\mu_b$ are fixed to each device. But we could say that we know their pdf because it is provided by the manufacturer.

Comment: I don't fully trust my understanding of this, but it seems that every
measurement $i$ provides an instance $x_{b_{i}}-x_{a_{i}}$ of random variable $\epsilon_{a}-\epsilon_{b}\sim N\left(\mu_{a}-\mu_{b},\sigma_{a}^{2}+\sigma_{b}^{2}\right)$.
This should enable you to estimate $\mu_{a}-\mu_{b}$.

Comment: @drhab For me this is a correct answer, but it is written as a comment now.

Comment: I have made it an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every measurement $i$ provides an instance $x_{b_i}-x_{a_i}$ of random variable $$\epsilon_a-\epsilon_b\sim\mathcal N(\mu_a-\mu_b,\sigma_a^2+\sigma_b^2)$$

This makes it possible to use these measurements by estimation of $\mu_a-\mu_b$.

You could use: $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{b_i}-x_{a_i})\sim \mathcal N(\mu_a-\mu_b,\frac{\sigma_a^2+\sigma_b^2}{n})$$

as unbiased estimator.